# flutter tracking progress for 30 day

Tags: flutter

i am a beginner at flutter and wondering how to implement tracking progress for 7 or 30 days/ to clarify what i mean: lets say that i want to track everyday's calories burned so now i have a variable which is `int CLB = caloriesBurned` then my question is that how to get everyday's CLB value and store it...similar as google fit tracking that everyday for 30 days it tracks footsteps and store it...then display it in a chart.
i am using Hive as my local store data to save everyday's value and i will use fl_chart package.

i know it will be a lot of things to be discussed but i need only the way of how can i store the data everyday of the same variable (which mean it will be reset to 0 value at the beginning of the day to track the new day's calories), any hints or keywords that will help me for searching on the internet of how to implement that exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track progress for a certain number of days, like 7 or 30, you need to store the data for each day. You're already using Hive to store your data, so we can use it to store your daily progress.

Here's what you can do:

Create a Hive box to store your daily data. A box is like a container to store your data in Hive. You can create a box with this code:

```
final dailyCaloriesBox = await Hive.openBox('dailyCalories');
```

Every day, create a new record in the Hive box to store the calories burned. You can use this code to create a new record:

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final key = '${now.year}-${now.month}-${now.day}';
final caloriesBurned = 500; // Replace this with your actual calories burned value.

dailyCaloriesBox.put(key, caloriesBurned);
```

To display the data in a chart, you can retrieve the data from the Hive box and use it to build the chart. You can use the query method of the Hive box to get all the records in the box:

```
final entries = dailyCaloriesBox.query();
```

You can use the fl_chart package to create a chart from the data. Here's some example code to create a simple line chart:

```
LineChartData(
  lineBarsData: [
    LineChartBarData(
      spots: entries.map((entry) {
        final dateParts = entry.key.split('-');
        final x = DateTime(int.parse(dateParts[0]), int.parse(dateParts[1]), int.parse(dateParts[2]));
        return FlSpot(x.millisecondsSinceEpoch.toDouble(), entry.value.toDouble());
      }).toList(),
      isCurved: true,
      colors: [Colors.blue],
    ),
  ],
  minX: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 6)).millisecondsSinceEpoch.toDouble(),
  maxX: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toDouble(),
  minY: 0,
)
```

This code will create a line chart that shows the calories burned over the last 7 days.